# about Plotly (how can I post it for my github pages?)

Tags: plotly

I usually write files on ipynb, convert them into markdown files using nbconvert, and post them on my GitHub page. my theme is minimal-mistakes.

I want to post the contents of the data visualization using plotly recently, but when I converted it to Markdown on ipynb by nbconvert, there was no result unlike the graph of seaborne.

I have a few questions.

1. Is the plotly graph not convertible when converting from ipynb to Markdown?
2. How to include plotly's graph in the markdown and upload it on the git hub page

Comment: If you create a plotly graph, you can save it as an image by clicking the camera icon in the header, and then mark it down on the Github markdown.

Comment: Isn't that just adding images?What I want to do is post the interactive graph itself. :)

Comment: I can't do that; I don't think Plotly will install in the Github environment.

Comment: I solved it using "iframe".

Comment: That's good to hear. By all means post your solution for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to use plotly graphs on the GitHub page, you must sign up for plotly and issue an api key.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import chart_studio
```

set your api

```
chart_studio.tools.set_credentials_file(username=username, api_key=api_key)
```

for example

```
fig = px.line(data, x="", y="" ... )
fig.show()

url = chart_studio.plotly.plot(fig, filename="what u want", auto_open=False)
chart_studio.tools.get_embed(url)
```

If you write it as above, you can get a graph and an iframe url on ipynb, and it works good when I convert md by nbconvert

I use it this way.

```
import plotly.express as px
import chart_studio as cs

fig = px.line(df, x=, y=, title=)
fig.show()

cs.tools.get_embed(cs.plotly.plot(fig, filename="what u want", auto_open=False))
```